# Use the same variable for two PHP functions

Tags: php, arrays, function, mysqli, global-variables

```
<?php require_once 'config.php';

// FUNCTION 1 BEGINS
        function saveInvoice( array $data){         if( !empty( $data ) ){              global $con;            $count = 0;             if( isset($data['data'] )){
                        foreach ($data['data'] as $value) {
                            if(!empty($value['length'] ))$count++;
                        }           }           if($count == 0)throw new Exception( "Please add atleast one item to warehouse form." );
         if( !empty( $data)){
                        $codigo1 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['codigo1'] ) );
                        $shipper = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['shipper'] ) );
                        $codigo2 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['codigo2'] ) );
                        $consignee = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['consignee'] ) );
                        $carrier = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['carrier'] ) );
                        $supplier = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['supplier'] ) );
                        $tracking = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['tracking'] ) );
                        $vlb_total = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['airtotal'] ) );
                        $ft3_total = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['oceantotal'] ) );
                        $weight_total = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['totalweight'] ) );
                        $method = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['method'] ) );
                        $user = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['user'] ) );
                        $office = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['office'] ) );
                        $notes = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['notes'] ) );
                        $total_air_usd = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['totalairusd'] ) );
                        $total_ocean_usd = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['totaloceanusd'] ) );

                        $warehouse = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['warehouse'] ) );

                        if(empty($warehouse)){
                            $uuid = uniqid();
                        $query = "INSERT INTO wreceipt (`warehouse`, `codigo1`, `shipper`, `codigo2`, `consignee`, `carrier`, `supplier`, `tracking`, `vlb_total`, `ft3_total`, `weight_total`, `method`, `user`, `office`, `notes`, `total_air_usd`, `total_ocean_usd`, `created`, `uuid`) VALUES ('', '$codigo1', '$shipper', '$codigo2', '$consignee', '$carrier', '$supplier', '$tracking', '$vlb_total', '$ft3_total', '$weight_total', '$method', '$user', '$office', '$notes', '$total_air_usd', '$total_ocean_usd', NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR, '$uuid')";
                        }else{
                            throw new Exception( "Please check, some of the required fields missing" );
                        }
                        if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)){
                            throw new Exception(  mysqli_error($con) );
                        }else{
                        if(empty($warehouse))$warehouse = mysqli_insert_id($con);
                        }

                        if( isset( $data['data']) && !empty( $data['data'] )){
                            saveInvoiceDetail( $data['data'], $warehouse );
                        }
                        return [
                            'success' => true,
                            'uuid' => $uuid,
                            'message' => 'Warehouse Saved Successfully.',
                            'warehouse' => $warehouse
                        ];          }else{
                        throw new Exception( "Please check, some of the required fields missing" );             }       } else{             throw new Exception( "Please check, some of the required fields missing" );         }   }
// FUNCTION 1 ENDS

// FUNCTION 2 BEGINS       
        function saveInvoiceDetail(array $wreceipt_items, $warehouse = ''){     global $con;

            foreach ($wreceipt_items as $wreceipt_item){
                $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['desc'] ) );
                $length = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['length'] ) );
                $width = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['width'] ) );
                $height = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['height'] ) );
                $weight = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['weight'] ) );
                $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['quantity'] ) );
                $volumeweight = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['volumeweight'] ) );
                $volume = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['volume'] ) );
                $weightrow = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['weightrow'] ) );

                $query = "INSERT INTO wreceipt_items (`id`, `warehouse`, `desc`, `length`, `width`, `height`, `weight`, `quantity`, `volumeweight`, `volume`, `weightrow`)
                        VALUES (NULL, '$warehouse', '$desc', '$length', '$width', '$height', '$weight', '$quantity', '$volumeweight', '$volume', '$weightrow' )";
                mysqli_query($con, $query);
            } }

        function getInvoices($warehouse){
                global $con;
                $data = [];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM wreceipt WHERE warehouse = '$warehouse'";
                if ( $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) ){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        array_push($data, $row);
                    }
                }    return $data; } ?>
// FUNCTION 2 ENDS
```

I have 2 functions: one registers and the other shows data. I am interested in the second one, since it does NOT take the value of the ***$warehouse*** variable (of the first function) to use it in the query of the second function exactly here: $query = "SELECT * FROM wreceipt WHERE warehouse = ***$warehouse***

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

```
PD: I use this for show the (function 2) data:

<?php 
$invoices = getInvoices($warehouse);

if( !empty( $invoices ) ){ 
foreach ($invoices as $value) {
$value['warehouse'];
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could perhaps be an issue of variable scope.  I can't see what variable `saveInvoice()` is being fed from your main script, but if you are passing a variable called `$data` which contains keys like `code`, `data`, and `warehouse` then this same array should be used on `getinvoices()` in your mainscript instead of `$invoices = getInvoices($warehouse);`

Again about variable scope inside of functions...

Inside of `function saveInvoice( array $data){`... `getInvoices($warehouse);` is valid to use because `$warehouse` is a declared variable with a value inside the function.

Outside of `saveInvoice()` the variable `$warehouse` does not exist (unless you have declared it to the global scope in the code not posted to this question).

For this reason, I think the solution would be (in your second posted block of code) to call `getInvoices()` something like this: `$invoices = getInvoices($data['warehouse']);`

---

---

Additionally, I would recommend that you not mysqli escape values that you will return.  My advice would be to use mysqli prepared statements in `saveInvoiceDetail()` and all other database querying functions.

Lastly, take a close look at the your array containing `success`.  It will return `success=>true` even if there was no success.  This part requires some more development.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i added " 'warehouse' => $warehouse " to the return and still dont work, i cant get the "warehouse" value. I just want this value for show it in other page with " echo ". Thanks in advance

Comment: @IrvıngNgr' You should write some "checkpoints" (echoes) throughout your function to see if the value is where you expect it to be...  like `$data['warehouse']` and revisit the flow of your if-statements.

Comment: @IrvıngNgr' I may have mis-read your question earlier.  Please show your var_export() check points on the generated arrays throughout your code.  After `$invoices = getInvoices($warehouse);` what is `var_export($invoices);`?

Comment: Also, you won't need to write `if(!empty($invoices)){` before the foreach loop.  The loop simply won't run if it is empty, and `getInvoices()` defaults a return value of an empty array -- so there should never be an error/warning.

Comment: There isn't enough code to help you on this yet.  I don't know if your `getInvoices($warehouse);` call is receiving a valid `$warehouse` value.

Comment: I think my advice to add `warehouse` to your return array was incorrect.  Now I am just guessing on the parts of your code that are missing, but perhaps try: `$invoices = getInvoices($data['warehouse']);`

Comment: @IrvıngNgr' I have updated my answer.  Hopefully, I have explained the issue of variable scope sufficiently.  If this doesn't solve your issue, please show more code and some sample data from `$data`.